# Why my output in printf is printing -nan and 0.0000 C language

Tags: c, terminal, printf

Here is line written in C and goes like this.

```
//declarations 
int hr, min;
float CHSnow  [143];
float ETime [143];
int Timer;
int CCSc;

printf("V, %i : %i je aktuálna výška snehu na letisku %f a odhadovaný čas pre bezpečné pristátie je %f minút \n", hr, min, CHSnow[Timer], ETime[CCSc] );
```

The output goes like this:
*V, 0 : 10 je aktuálna výška snehu na letisku **-nan** a odhadovaný čas pre bezpečné pristátie je **0.000000** minút .*

I'm asking you what could go wrong in that bold output variables?
Thank you,
Matoosh

Comment: This is quiet incomplete. What are: `CHSnow`, `Timer`, `ETime` and `CCSc`. This is not a guessing game.

Comment: You have been a member for long enough to know [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In floating point numbers, [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) is an acronym for "Not a Number", which usually results by doing an invalid operation with floating point numbers.

If the number is un-representable, `nan` will be printed.

This can happen because of uninitialized data or an invalid operation.

As for the "wrong" 0.000000, there's literally nothing anyone one stackoverflow can tell you that you don't know, as we do not have the full code to look at.

Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: Thanks, I've found  that it's exactly NAN for the reason of 0s.                                   Breakpoint 1, main () at let.c:150
150    CHSnow[Timer] = SSnow/ N ;  /* vypocet */
(gdb) print N
$1 = 0
(gdb) print SSnow
$2 = 0
(gdb)